# .htaccess RewriteRule doesn't work on my site

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

how i can rewrite this url:

```
http://www.example.com/delete-album?album_id=52
```

to this:

```
http://www.example.com/album/52/delete
```

this is my .htaccess code and it doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^album/([0-9]+)/?$/delete delete-album?album_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Look up what the `$` character means. Realize why it makes no sense to have that in the middle of your regex.

Answer (score 0):

You regex is incorrect in your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^(album)/(\d+)/(delete)/?$ $3-$1?album_id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```